# Is it possible to update an Entity with jpaRepository, using the Entity as parameter? And how?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, entity

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "UPDATE Item i "
    + "SET i = :item "
    + "WHERE i.id = :itemId"
)
int updateItem(
        @Param("item") Item item,
        @Param("itemId") String itemId
);
```

This method returns 1, as if the update was succesfull, but when I check the Database, the item is not updated. If I pass specific column value, it can be updated, but I want to know if this is possible.

Comment: Make sure the transaction has been committed.

Comment: You can do it by adding @Transactional annotation to the updateItem method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make update action with Entity object you can use save(YourEntity entity) method provided by spring. It saves in db if that entity not exists and updates if it is already exists.
Your mentioned case is for patch, for update specific fields for entity.